# Which is the correct formula for compound interest when time period in t years and m months

Tags: education

I have two formula to calculate compound interest if period is t years and m months.

$$CI =P(1+\frac{R}{100})^T [1+\frac{mR}{1200}] $$ and

$CI=P(1+\frac{R}{100})^T$

Now I have a question where Principal amount is 15000, R = 6% and Time is 2 year and 4 months

From Formula (1), I get 17191.08 as my compound amount.

But form second formula using $T=2+\frac{4}{12}=7/3$ years

I get 17184.5 as compound amount. There is difference of 6.58 between two answer.

Why aren't both the answers the same and what is wrong here ?

Comment: For the second formula $$15000\left(1+\frac 6{100}\right)^{\frac 7 3}=17184.5545$$

Comment: Sorry @ClaudeLeibovici I edited my question.

Comment: You are missing something. Basically your first expression is second expression times something which I don't know where it comes from. That's why you are getting a difference